# Multiple customer groups per customer

Tags: magento

Is it possible to put customers in multiple customer groups in Magento?

e.g.  Customer "Dupant," in groups "Wholesale" & "Retailer."

Comment: Have you tried it in the admin panel? This would seem to be trivial to test.

Comment: Look under Customers->Customer Groups in the admin area.

Comment: nope, it not possible to do that there !

Comment: @Joseph, That is the most unhelpful comment I have seen on stack overflow. This is something that is a real hole in the functionality of Magento, so no it's not in the admin area.

Comment: That takes you to the page for adding and editing groups, not the page for adding customers to groups.

Comment: Lots of love on same feature here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19807/

Comment: There we can only cretae customer groups not assign multiple groups .

Answer (score 1):

There is similar question on SO here: [assign customer to multiple customer groups to magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528327/assign-customer-to-multiple-customer-groups-to-magento).

However, I'm not sure if the answer provided is universal because the following snippet 
`$customer->getGroupId()`
is used quite a lot in Magento core, where it is also supposed that group ID returned from this method is integer and *not* a string (comma separated list of IDs).