# assign customer to multiple customer groups to magento

Tags: php, magento

Hello I want to assign multiple groups to particular customer like "Rajat the customer" belogs to "Wholesale,retailer,electric". actually I saw the same thread on [Multiple customer groups per customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153011/multiple-customer-groups-per-customer-magento) but it is not helpful does there any update to make this change happen.

I am stuck what should I do because there aren't any extension available with the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution,

First of all go to database and click on the `eav_attribute` and then search for `group_id` in the attribute code field and edit this record.

now Step 1:-

change `frontend_input` from `select` to `multiselect`.

step 2:-

change `backend_type` from `static` to `varchar`.

although it is not standard way but it worked for me. :)

PS. I'm using magento 1.7.0.2 community version.

Comment: looking back was there any repercussions in doing this?  Ie: if I do something sort of like this from a module, was there anything that needed to be accounted for or walls that you hit?

Comment: Promotion price rules are not set, if changing `customer group` as `select` to `multiselect`.

Comment: @Helohin: Can you tell me how you have achieve this in promotions.

Answer (score 1):

Rajat Modi's solution worked pretty well for me thank you but doing this did break the display of the groups column on the customer grid if more than one is selected, plus broke the ability to filter customers by group.

To fix that, create this file to use as the renderer for customer groups: `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Renderer/Group.php`

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Renderer_Group
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
$value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
$groups = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('in' => explode(',', $value)));
$groupNames = array();
foreach ($groups as $group)
{
$groupNames[] = $group->getCustomerGroupCode();
}
return implode(', ', $groupNames);
}
}
```

Then override /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php`enter code here` (copy it to `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php`)

In the `_prepareColumns()` function, change this (around line 95):

```
$this->addColumn('group', array(
'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
'width'     =>  '100',
'index'     =>  'group_id',
'type'      =>  'options',
'options'   =>  $groups,
));
```

to this:

```
$this->addColumn('group_id', array(
'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
'width'     =>  '100',
'index'     =>  'group_id',
'type'      =>  'options',
'options'   =>  $groups,
'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Renderer_Group',
'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterGroupCondition')
));
```

then it will use that class for rendering groups on the grid.

Also in the `_prepareCollection()` function, around line 52 find `->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')` and add after: `->addAttributeToSelect('customer_group_id')`

Having multiple groups per customer also seems to interfere with tiered pricing (where a product has a different price depending on customer group). To fix that on the frontend display...
Fix for customer group-based product pricing tiers when calculating on the front-end:

In */app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php*
Around line 138, FIND:
`$customerGroup = $this->_getCustomerGroupId($product);`
ADD AFTER:
`$customerGroups = explode(',',$customerGroup);`

FIND:
`if ($groupPrice['cust_group'] == $customerGroup && $groupPrice['website_price'] < $matchedPrice) {`
REPLACE WITH:
`if (in_array($groupPrice['cust_group'],$customerGroups) && $groupPrice['website_price'] < $matchedPrice) {`

Do the same thing in */app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Price.php* if you use bundles.

I do not yet have a fix for displaying the customer group tier price when creating an order or reorder from the backend dashboard - they just show up the standard product prices.

Finally, when figuring all this out we did have some instances where `mgnt_catalog_product_entity_group_price` got emptied and I'm still not sure why it happened, so do make sure to take backups. For that table I restored it from an SQL backup, but re-indexing things and maybe flushing the Magento cache is also often required when getting into this stuff.

When doing things such as searching for customers by group programmatically in your own scripts or modules you may have to take into account that it is now a multiselect for example by doing things like this:

```
$allowedGroups = array(
array(
"finset" => array(10)
),
array(
"finset" => array(42)
)
);
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $allowedGroups);
```

Although I'm not sure that that piece of code will work right until all the customers have rows in the `mgnt_customer_entity_varchar` table which is where the new value for a customer's groups is stored when there are more than one group selected. Only a single group ID remains stored in `mgnt_customer_entity` as that field isn't varchar.

**For that reason be aware that yes it can affect modules which extend or use the functionality of customer groups.**

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Have you come across any modules that roll this up into an installable, upgrade safe package?

Comment: That's ok glad it was helpful. I haven't come across any modules, considering making one but I still have the issue of the group tiered pricing not coming up when creating orders/re-orders from the backend dashboard, and doing this has interfered with 3 other modules that I've used so far so I don't think this method would ever quite be 'safe' although they were quite easy to workaround/resolve by editing those modules.

Where I wrote to edit the core Price.php that should be made as a a copy in local really. Then just a case of checking & re-doing stuff after an upgrade for now.

Comment: @Tom Rice: Can you tell me how you have achieve this in promotions.