# Magento add discount for a single user (Not user usergroup)

Tags: php, magento

Is there any ways I can add a fx 10% discount for a single user? (Not a usergroup)

Or is the only option to add each user to its own usergroup?

In promotion > Catalog Price Rules its not possible to add a user attribute, only choose usergroups.

(Shopping Cart Price Rules is not an option, because the prices is only viewable in the cart, and not in the catalog)

Answer (score 1):

Create new user group, then add that user(only) to that created user-group. Create new prize rule for that user-group only..That's it..You can't assign prize rule for single user until modify the core system..

**Update :**

Well..You cant add single customer in multi user groups by default magento config. But you can achieve this by simple alteration in database. I found this solution here. ***[CLICK ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528327/assign-customer-to-multiple-customer-groups-to-magento)*** .(Look at last answer). If you think it will fix your problem just try it out..!.It seem like it will work. But I didnt tried it out.

Comment: The problem is that users are already in another usergroup, because some price rules are based on user group, and other price rules are on that single user. (And both a usergroup and a single user can have multiple rules applied - fx 2% for being in the group, and another 5% for being that specific user, and as far I as I know, a user cant be in multiple groups)